# how to add crossorigin='anonymous' from js to script

Tags: javascript, http, cross-domain

```
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.async = true;
            script.src = url;
            script.crossorigin="anonymous"

            const element = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];

            element.parentNode.insertBefore(script, element);

            script.onload = () => {
                resolve(script);
            }
```

As you can see, I am setting `crossorigin` in there, but it turns out that when I see the `html` , script doesn't have `crossorigin`.  Basically , I don't want to have `opaque` response, so how do I set `crossorigin` correctly ?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLScriptElement

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong attribute name. It's `crossOrigin` in camelCase